# Copying a derived object from a base object (smart) pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Lets say I have two classes, `Base` and `Derived` that have a variable to tell whether or not the object is of type `Derived`:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() : is_derived(false) {}
    bool is_derived;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : is_derived(true) {}
    int derived_only_member;
};
```

I have a `std::set` of `std::shared_ptr`'s to `Base` objects:

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Base> > bases;
// Populate this set one way or another
```

I have a need to iterate through the set and copy only the `Derived` objects into another similar set of `Base` shared pointers:

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Base> > copies;
for(auto &b: bases) {
    if(b->is_derived) {
        copies.insert(/*Somehow copy the `Derived` object and assign a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` to it */);
    }
}
```

If I know the `Base` pointer is pointing to a `Derived` object, how can I copy it so that the copy has the same value for `derived_only_member`?

Is there a way to do this without a copy constructor that has an argument for every member variable that `Derived` has and `Base` doesn't? My real version of `Derived` has many members, so this would be impractical.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this without a copy constructor that has an argument for every member variable that `Derived` has and `Base` doesn't?

Copy constructors don't need arguments for every member variable. The compiler also already generates one for you.

What you need there is a cast:

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Base> > copies;
for(auto &b: bases) {
    if(b->is_derived) {
        copies.insert(std::make_shared<Derived>(static_cast<Derived>(*b)));
                                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^ 
    }
}
```

---

Note:

You don't even need the `is_derived` member to check for instances being derived from `Base`. You can use a `dynamic_cast` instead:

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Base> > copies;
for(auto &b: bases) {
    Derived* org = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b.get());
    if(org) {
        copies.insert(std::make_shared<Derived>(*org));
    }
}
```

Comment: And the copy will have the same value for `derived_only_member` as the original `Derived` object?

Comment: @Kai Sure, it will.